# How can I uninstall Ubuntu in order to install Windows 7?

Tags: installation, windows, hard-drive, format

I can't work out how to do it. When I try to use my Windows installation disk, it won't even show a setup menu.

I installed Ubuntu via a USB stick, and it is the only OS on my hard drive.

Comment: What I really want to do is format my Hard Drive into a format that I can install Windows from my disk.

Comment: I can't get the autorun.inf file on the Windows 7 disk to open, or the setup.exe. I have no idea what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do with ubuntu. In time of installation you can format your disk from windows setup.

If you are using Windows disk,

- Open up BIOS.
- Change boot-priority to boot from optical disk first.

If you are using USB installation of Windows

- Open up BIOS with device plugged in.
- Change boot-priority to boot from USB.

Your USB may be detected as HDD,only in such case in boot-priority select HDD as first one.
Then in HDD order change the order to list the USB before your hard disk. You should be able to boot.

If you are sure, you are booting from correct media, still windows setup doesn't start then the disk is corrupt or not bootable.

Comment: Whenever I try to set boot priority to my disk drive or some sort of disk, all it is doing is opening Linux normally, and I can't seem to work out how to get the disk to run while I am booted into Linux, as Linux doesn't seem to like .exe or .inf file types.

Comment: you need to put the disk before booting starts

Comment: and remember your windows disk must be bootable. this is a complete windows question and you will get more help at windows forum. See here - http://www.buildeasypc.com/sw/windows_7/install_windows_7.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ubuntu USB to format the Drive to NTFS and then put the Windows CD or whatever you use

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that that particualar USB stick now contains other stuff, as I needed it for college work.

Comment: Anyway, I think the solution is to use a tool to format the drive to NTFS to be detected by the windows setup menu

Comment: I think having ubuntu in hard disk doesn't prevent you from booting  windows disk. isn't it? And windows installation disk is capable of formatting the disk in NTFS.

Comment: As far as I know, ext file systems are not detected in windows installation menu

Comment: It may be trying to open the .exe file on the disk in the wrong program, but I can't work out what to open it with.

Comment: ext filesystem is not detected but partition detected and you can delete, format the partition